# iOS - indexPathForRowAtPoint don't return correct indexPath with different cell height

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have UITableView that contains many cell. User can expand cell to see more content in this cell by push the expand button in this cell (only 1 cell can expand at time):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(selectedRowIndex == indexPath.row) return 205;
    else return 60;
}
```

In the storyboard, I drag UILongPressGesture into cell button and named it longPress (cell is custom, it has 2 buttons in it, 1 need to recognize LongPressGesture, the other expand cell height):

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress;
```

And in the viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{      
    [longPress addTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
}
```

It's work perfectly, however when I use following code to recognize cell indexPath, it's wrong when one cell is expanded:

```
- (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)sender {         
    // Get index path
    slidePickerPoint = [sender locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath= [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:slidePickerPoint]; 
    // It's wrong when 1 cell is expand and the cell's button I hold is below the expand button
}
```

Can anyone please show me how to get correct indexPath when there're different cell height?
Thank in advance

Comment: Please add some code for how you've added the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` and how you've handled the expansion of cells, or else you won't get good answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do it would be to add a UILongPressGestureRecognizer to each UITableViewCell (that all use the same selector), then when the selector is called you can get the cell via sender.view. Perhaps not the most memory efficient, but if the single gesture recognizer won't return the right row in certain situations, this way should work.

Something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ...

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] 
  initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
    [longPress setMinimumPressDuration:2.0];
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
    [longPress release];

    return cell;
}
```

then

```
- (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)sender {  
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = sender.view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First add the long press gesture recognizer to the table view:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] 
  initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 2.0; //seconds
lpgr.delegate = self;
[self.myTableView addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];
[lpgr release];
```

Then in the gesture handler:

```
-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
  if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
  { 
    CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.myTableView];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];
    if (indexPath == nil)
        NSLog(@"long press on table view but not on a row");
    else
        NSLog(@"long press on table view at row %d", indexPath.row);
    } 
}
```

You have to be careful with this so that it doesn't interfere with the user's normal tapping of the cell and also note that handleLongPress may fire multiple times before user lifts their finger.

Thanks...!

Comment: This tutorial doesn't deal with UIGestureRecognizer, which is what he wants to use to detect Long Press. Doesn't seem to solve his issue.

Comment: Is it just my imagination, or is your answer *exactly* the same as his current code (which doesn't work on expanded cells)?

Comment: @Dinesh Don't worry about votes...worry about the quality of your answers