# UITableViewCell indexPathForRowAtPoint always returns nil

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to use a custom disclosure button as per Apple's example.  I'm doing the following

```
- (void) customButtonTapped:(UIButton *)sender event: (id) event{

    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];
    NSLog(@"index path %@", indexPath);
    if (indexPath != nil)
    {

    }


}
```

The problem is that index path is always nil.   Every time without fail.  Has anyone else come across this?

**EDIT**
This is how I'm adding the button

```
 cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Gear"];
 UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
 button.frame = frame;
 [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 [button addTarget:self action:@selector(customButtonTapped:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 cell.accessoryView = button;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS - indexPathForRowAtPoint don't return correct indexPath with different cell height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459837/ios-indexpathforrowatpoint-dont-return-correct-indexpath-with-different-cell)

Comment: I added a button to my cell and copied your code -- worked fine for me. How did you add your button?

Comment: NSLog the value of self.tableView and make sure it isn't nil.

Comment: Oh My God.  Anna you're awesome.  I set the delegate and datasource for the table in IB, but forgot to set the table property.  And... I'm an idiot.

Comment: So is this worth leaving up or should I delete this question altogether?

Comment: I've answered in case it's useful to others.  Feel free to delete/close if you (or others) prefer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to `indexPathForRowAtPoint:` can return `nil` if `self.tableView` is `nil`.

Make sure `self.tableView` is set (eg. if it's an IBOutlet, make sure it is connected to the table view in the xib).