# how to get .indexPathForItem(at: CGPoint) in SWIFT to return correct indexPath with respect to 0 as the first cell?

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

EDIT**: I found the solution; just updating this here hoping that it might be helpful for someone else. They is to find out how much collection view has been scrolled and take that into account when calculating the coordinates given to the .indexPathForItem(at CGPoint)

So I'm struggling to get the cell I longPress in a collection view and then I'd like to drag and basically color all the cells until when longPress state is .Ended. 
I have eventually got to the point that I'm using something like the code below but;

the indexPath isn't returned taking into account how much I have scrolled up or down and so if maximum number of visible cells are initially 20 that is going to always be the maximum indexPath.row even when there are more than 20 cells in total in my collection view and I have scrolled down. I know why, as the coordinates always originate from the visible part of the view. I just can't think of or find any other solution.

```
//action when click on the collection view; for making an event
func pressed(sender : UIGestureRecognizer){
    let view = sender.view
    let point = sender.location(in: view)

    //for now, just trying to return correct indexPath
    if sender.state == .began {




        let indexPath = self.dayViewCollection.indexPathForItem(at: point)
        if let index = indexPath {
            let cell = self.dayViewCollection.cellForItem(at: index)
            cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
            // do stuff with your cell, for example print the indexPath
            print(indexPath?.row)
        } else {
            print("Could not find index path")
        }




    }
    else if sender.state == .changed {

    }   else if sender.state == .ended {

    }
}
```

How could I get the correct indexPath from where I longPress that would take into account the original number of cells and not just what the view can show?

I have tried a few other ways to access cells from either the cell class or in didselectItemAtIndexPath but none seem to be the right approach. The only reference to indexPathForItem I can find in SO is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459837/ios-indexpathforrowatpoint-dont-return-correct-indexpath-with-different-cell) and doesn't seem to address the issue.

EDIT: I'm thinking perhaps I need to calculate how much I have scrolled and add that to the y coordinate? if I can do that it should return the correct indexPath but not sure how to get the amount of scrolling.

EDIT2: I think offset is the key in order to figure this out.

Comment: https://github.com/lxcid/LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout

Comment: is your comment supposed to help me in anyway? sorry, I don't get it.